# Find number of elements in array matching query

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following class:

```
public class Words
{
    public string word;
    public bool correct;
}
```

and I have an array of Words.

```
Words[] words;
```

I wish to count how many elements in my array have the property `correct` set to true.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Most efficient would be keep track of how elements have the property `correct` set to true, so you don't have to count them.

Comment: Depends @dtb, that isn't always the best options.

Comment: I agree with KingCronus. Plus it would require storing an extra variable, which would only make the code more messy. I believe that the LINQ solution is more elegant and definitely answers my question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using **LINQ**

```
words.Where(w=>w.correct);
```

That should do the trick to filter.

---

But if you only want to count:

```
words.Count(w=>w.correct);
```

Comment: I knew it was something like that, I just didn't know the correct syntax/method :) Thank you very much!